# Correct MySQL database layout

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Creating a custom CRM system i ran into a wall figuring out the correct way for MySQL layout. The system has to be dynamic, ie. expandable for multiple new products over time.
Each product should have individual billing and each contact should have multiple products.

Should i use tables like this:

```
Contacts{ ID }
Product_1{ ID; FK_ID; +Custom columns}
Product_2{ ID; FK_ID; +Custom columns}
Product_3{ ID; FK_ID; +Custom columns}
+ 15 more products (Expanding)
```

Or should i use something like this:

```
Contacts{ ID }
Products{ ID; FK_ID; +100 other columns (expanding)}
```

The first example will be easy to configure, but will contain a lot of tables over time.
Also binding contacts to products will need another table.

The last example will be easier configuring in PHP, but will be a mess looking at the table.

Any other ideas? Which is faster of the two? Which is most "common"?

I get the feeling that none of these solutions are optimal, there has to be a better way?

Comment: Why do you need different columns for each product? Neither approach you suggested looks good. You should try to make things more generic, finding the similarities between all the different products. You might still end up with a handful of different tables and columns (for different product types, for example) but that will still be an improvement.

Comment: The products have very little in common, so not really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your products are really that different from one another, create a separate table for each one:

```
Product_1{ Product_ID (PK); +Custom columns}
Product_2{ Product_ID (PK); +Custom columns}
...
```

Now, take it a step further with these tables:

```
Product {ID (PK auto increment); Contact_ID (FK), Type_ID (FK)}
Product_Type {Type_ID (PK); Type_Name}
```

Insert as many rows in Product_Type as you have custom product tables (`Product_1`, `Product_2`, etc). Everytime you create a new specific product table, add a row to the `Product_Type` table.

Also make the `Product_n.Product_ID` a foreign key (and NOT auto increment) to `Product.ID`.

This way, you can refer to any type of product generically via the `Product` table or specifically via the correct `Product_n` table. You can even tell what type of product it is just by looking at `Product.Type_ID`.

If you want to make it completely bulletproof, you can add the `Type_ID` column to each `Product_n` table, include it in the PK (along with `Product_n.Product_ID`) and add a check constraint such that `Product_1.Type_ID == 1`, `Product_2.Type_ID == 2` and so. That will ensure that you can't screw up the relationship between `Product` and `Product_n` even if you try but, to be honest, I think it's overkill and I haven't had problems with the "non-bulletproof" version.

Comment: This pretty much sounds like the idea we where exploring.
Now if i only had the Contact.ID of a customer and wanted to select all products related to this customer, how do you suggest achieving this?
Would you select all Product_Type.Type_Name and create an sql innerjoin command containing all the different product tables and then sorting by Contact_ID = the ID i need products from ?

This is based on the Product_Type.Type_Name containing the table name of each product, which i guess was the idea?

Comment: Considering i would like each Contact to be capable of having multiple versions of each product, i guess i should have an unique ID and not a foreign key to Product.ID? Or maybe both?

Comment: If you need to know which products a contact has (in other words, which product IDs), use the ``Product`` table. If you need to know the details of each product, you will need to join the relevant ``Product_n`` but I think it's unlikely that you would actually do that in a single query. How would your application display all that information?

Comment: Do you mean you have version A and B (or 1.0 and 2.0) of Product 1? What are the differences between the versions? Do they need different columns, and therefor different tables?

Comment: A customer can purchase multiple products of the same type, so no fields will be identical, but all the fields will be the same within the same product. So we need two rows in the table Product_n for two products, for the same contact.id

Comment: Sorry i guess i misread your comment, i see how you would have all products in the table Products now. Please ignore my latest comment.

Comment: Make sure you're clear on what a row in ``Product_n`` represents. As an analogy with cars, it might be a "Porsche 911" or it might be "Andrew Francis' Porsche 911" (yeah, I wish) or it might be something else. The former comes in many colors, the latter is silver. Depending on which representation you mean, you will need to deal with the tables differently.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39914/discussion-between-jeppe-and-acfrancis)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider introducing a third table to store the dynamic "features":

```
Contacts{ Id; }
Products{ Id; }
ProductFeature{ Id; ProductId; FeatureName, FeatureValue }
```

This does make it more complicated to query, but has the advantage of not requiring a schema change for each new product or feature

Comment: Meta tables like that are usually a bad idea in the long run. Every ``FeatureValue`` will have to be a varchar or something similar and the application will have to implicitly know what type each individual feature actually is. That's only the beginning of your problems. Don't do it.